# COUNTIFS multiple columns by multiple columns as date compare

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, countif

```
=COUNTIFS(
  'NEW V2.0'!L3:L, "<>", 
  'NEW V2.0'!C3:C, S2, 
  'NEW V2.0'!I3:I, "<="&'NEW V2.0'!L3:L
)
```

Supposedly this formula should return  **1** however, I don't get what is missing here...

I am trying to count dates in `I` column that are bigger than the dates in `L` column.

```
| I           | L           |
|-------------|-------------|
| 20-Sep-2019 | 16-Sep-2019 |
| 20-Sep-2019 | 20-Sep-2019 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I am trying to count dates in I column that are bigger than the dates in L columns."*

In Excel:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(I1:I2>L1:L2))
```

In GS:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(I1:I>L1:L)
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining how the Excel version works? How exactly does -- work?

Comment: @M.Schalk, it's a double negative. `(I1:I2>L1:L2)` will return an array of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values. Multiply that by a double negative turns it into `1`s and `0`s. One could also opt to use: `=SUMPRODUCT((I1:I2>L1:L2)*1)` which essentially is the same. For better understanding you could use the build-in `Evaluate` option to step through the formula.

Comment: I see, thanks for that! I wasn't clear on what exactly is returned by SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: That did worked with the extra column required for all the filtering :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, I think the easiest approach would be a helper column. So, in column K put the following formula into row 2 and copy it down to the end of your data.

```
=IF(I2>L2,"Higher", "Lower")
```

Then simply put this formula below your data in column K (replace 10 with the actual last row of your data):

```
=COUNTIF(K2:K10, "Higher")
```

**EDIT:**
I found a more elegant solution to your exact question, try this:

```
=SUM(IF(I2:I3>J2:J3,1,0))
```

Please note that this is an array formula, so after entering the formula you have to press `Ctr + Shift + Enter` for it to work

Comment: Way too far out of scope

Comment: @dev Great way to show appreciation to people trying to solve your problems for you...

Answer (score 1):

please refer the below-updated formula

```
=COUNTIFS(
  'NEW V2.0'!L3:L, ">0", 
  'NEW V2.0'!I3:I, "<="&'NEW V2.0'!L3:L
)
```

You can use >0 to detect blank cells

Comment: Not relevant to my question

Comment: @dev It also doing the same thing, its checking that column L should not have blank space &  column L values higher than the column I value